# Ways to accept value from external application in ASP.NET core app launch?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to accept GUID in ASP.NET core application from another application. Could you please suggest me how I can accept GUID on launch for validation?

My Scenario is like this-

I have older application running in IIS. On same server, I will be deploying new ASP.NET core application.
I want to provide facility to accept GUID from older application into current ASP.NET core application. Basically, my older web application launches new ASP.NET core application.

Only way I can think about at this moment is to -

Accept GUID value from default route i.e. Home/Index/Guid and apply my validation logic here.

**What are the ways to accept value (in my case GUID) when my application URL is hit for the first time?**

Comment: How do you launch the application from your legacy ASP.NET application? If you run it with commandline to set an environment variable prior to start and use `AddEnvironmentVariables()` in your Startup.cs, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#using-the-built-in-sources

Comment: I am using AJAX Jquery to launch new application URL. In this, I can pass extra parameter. I am using environment variables to maintain ASPNETCORE variable across different environment like DEV, TEST and PROD.

Comment: @Tseng I am open for any other options too. Only thing is - open asp.net core application from older application and capture values from on launch.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? Ajax/JavaScript is client sided and the web app runs on the server

Comment: Ignore my option and suggest other options to capture values from on launch.

Comment: Like I said, solution heavily depends on how you start the application. If you let IIS start it, your options may be very limited and rather unpredictable if it starts before or after your legacy application. If you start it with dotnet cli tools, you can use command line and environment variable, but its harder to make it work behind IIS as `UseIISIntegration` won't work then. Also when running in IIS, IIS controls its lifetime and can stop/restart it at any time. If you run docker container / on linux, its bit easier as you dont depend on IIS for lifecylce/reverse proxy

Comment: As I mentioned in my question- I am using IIS to run my application. So what are my options?

Comment: Any more information on the use case? Is it an configuration value (like sharing Application Insight ID) or is it some kind of tenant system (every user stats his own application that's independent of the other users applications). Any reason why you can't share this guid via configuration files?

Comment: Could you please either share some code? or explain in more detail what you want with GUID? Please be more specific towards the behavior you want.

Comment: @Tseng Imagine this value as user specific. hence cannot stored in appsettings.json